# Relax, it’s just a riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> My prefix might make you feel the weight of the world
>   My infix might make you feel low to the ground
>   My suffix might make you feel old and tired
>   But all of me put together might make you feel good

**What am I?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must be a

> **MASSAGE**

*My prefix might make you feel the weight of the world*

> A large **"MASS-"** means a heavy weight

*My infix might make you feel low to the ground*

> I feel low to the ground when I **"-SAG-"** (not the other infix in there)

*My suffix might make you feel old and tired*

> Please don't remind me of my **"-AGE"**

*But all of me put together might make you feel good*

> I'll take a back or shoulder massage right about now

I like how there's a sense of lethargy until the last line.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Answer (score 1):

I think anodyne has the right answer. My thinking was a bit different, so posting it below.

You are a

> **MASSAGE**

*My prefix might make you feel the weight of the world*

> **MA**. Newton’s second law suggests force = mass * acceleration (F = m*a). Additionally, newton’s third laws suggests that when a body exerts a force on a second body, the second body exerts a force equal in magnitude and opposite in direction of the first body. So when we stand on earth, we feel the force of the entire world!

*My infix might make you feel low to the ground*

> **SS**. The Schutzstaffel was a major paramilitary organization and their actions can still make people feel really down and sad.

*My suffix might make you feel old and tired*

> **AGE**. As your age goes up you start feeling old and tired :(

*But all of me put together might make you feel good*

> A **MASSAGE** feels good!!

Comment: Seemed to take the more obscure angles, but +1 for a unique answer with the same answer?